# convert hex decimal numbers to decimal using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a binary file with hexa decimal numbers in 16 bits per row. I need to extract just three bytes( which I hav done already) and convert to decimal value and arrange them in ascending order and re convert them to hexa decimal value and store in a binary file.

Comment: You say your file is "binary" but also that it contains hexadecimal (which is a text format using only characters 0-9 and A-F). Which is it? Are you viewing the binary file using a hex editor, which presents the binary contents as hexadecimal? Also, what do you mean by "row" when you say there are 16 bits per row. Are there newlines in the file or is there some other binary delimiter?

Comment: I view the file in hex editor and so referred to as 16 bytes per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm updating my answer based on your additional information.  You didn't provide a context, an idea of what your dataset size was like, etc, so I'm not sure if this is suitable for your needs.

It's not the only answer, and I am not claiming it's the best answer, but it works and maybe it will at least be something you can work with.

```
fi = open('myinput.dat', 'rb')
fo = open('myoutput.dat', 'wb')

out_list = []

bytes_in = fi.read(3)
while bytes_in != '':
    print bytes_in
    out_list.append( bytearray([bytes_in[1], bytes_in[0], bytes_in[2]]) )
    print out_list
    bytes_in = fi.read(3)

out_list.sort()

for bytes_out in out_list:
    fo.write(bytes_out)

fo.close()   
fi.close()
```

This would take a dataset that would look like:

```
Hexadecimal:      |  ASCII
0x61 0x62 0x63    |  abc
0x31 0x32 0x33    |  123
0x41 0x42 0x43    |  ABC
```

And will output:

```
Hexadecimal:   |  ASCII
0x32 0x31 0x33 |  213
0x42 0x41 0x43 |  BAC
0x61 0x62 0x63 |  bac
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: The hexa decimal numbers are actually in the form AA BB CC but I want it to be re ordered as BB AA CC for every three bytes and then all the reordered bytes to be put in ascending order.

Comment: So you want the entire list to be sorted, not the bytes?  
  
Like if you have input:  "AA BB CC 11 22 33 CC FF 3F"


The output would be:

"22 33 11 BB AA CC FF CC 3F"
  
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You know, I'm new to answering these questions and perhaps I was a little too eager to jump in, but honestly I think you really should be more specific on what exactly is the problem, and show some examples of your effort so that we can see what the problem is better and to better show that you've made some effort yourself.  As it is, I don't know whether your problem is your understanding of the file access, the sorting, or what.  Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for helping.                                                 I have a binary file with AA BB CC 11 22 33 CC FF 3F ...... I want it to be like (22 11 33) (BB AA CC) (FF CC 3F) the braces are just to make things clear. First to separate the file by clustering three bytes together , then re order every three byte from positions 123 to 213, then order the whole file in ascending order. I think I am clear now.

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind accepting that answer then?  I'd appreciate it. (I'm new to answering and still don't have reputation to do a lot of basic things).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hex bytes in readable form then use the decimal value as the key for the sort.

```
hlist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x, 16))
```

If you have the raw hex bytes and they're all the same length then you don't need an explicit key, since bytestrings sort naturally.

```
hlist.sort()
```

Comment: My file is like AA BB CC DD EE FF.... with 16 fields in a row in a binary file viewed using a hex editor. I need to first split them 3 numbers first and re order them as BBAACC and in the same way split and re order next three bytes. Atlast on the whole re order the full file by clubbing three bytes.